# Magento2 RC - Frontend theme not showing

Tags: theme, magento2, backend

I created a theme on Magento 2 1.0.0beta. Now I updated to Magento 2.0.0 RC. After this update, my theme does not show up anymore on the Content > Themes page.

What I did to update my theme

- I changed the xsd scheme from lib internal to urn:magento:framework:
- I added registration.php

I also tried to add my theme directly to the theme database table. After this my theme does show up. But when I activate the theme I get this error:

`Required parameter 'theme_dir' was not passed`

Do I have to do something additional to make my theme work? Or do I need to activate it somehow?

Comment: Same problem here. The error comes from `vendor/magento/framework/View/Design/Fallback/Rule/Theme.php:65` - `componentRegistrar->getPath()` does not return a path, so the `theme_dir` in the array is null.

Comment: Did you add a `composer.json` for your theme ?

Comment: I have composer.json file in my theme, but the theme itself is not loaded via composer.

Comment: I made another question for that: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/89421/in-magento2-rc-does-every-module-and-theme-need-to-be-pulled-via-composer

Comment: Try http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/89423/81

Answer (score 3):

I bet you have your theme in `app/design` and not pulled from external via composer to `vendor/`.

I think the problem is, that your registration.php is not run. It is referenced from `composer.json`. But the question is, how to make your `registration.php` known to the system.

Additionally there seems to be a bug, where `registration.php` of non-composer modules is not loaded. Fix see here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/89446/81

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the following command from the Magento 2 root folder:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

If it doesn't work, then you may use `sudo` at front:

```
sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```