# In Magento2 RC, does every module and theme need to be pulled via composer?

Tags: magento2, composer

I added `registration.php` to my custom (project specific) modules and themes. But those files do not end up in `vendor/composer/autoload_files.php` after `composer.phar dumpautoload` - so the modules are not registered.

How can I make my code in `app/code` and `app/design` known to Magento and/or composer to load the `registration.php` ?

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if this applies anymore, but I added `registration.php` for my module (a few minor versions ago), ran `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` and my module was recognized without touching composer.

**[EDIT]**
I just tested this on the latest available version (rc) and it works the same.
I add the `registration.php` file for modules:

```
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    '[Namespace]_[Module]',
    __DIR__
);
```

and run `setup:upgrade` and the module is recognized.

For theme I added `registration.php`:

```
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::THEME,
    'frontend/[Namespace]/[theme]',
    __DIR__
);
```

added `theme.xml`

```
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
    <title>[Title here]</title>
    <parent>Magento/blank</parent>
    <media>
        <preview_image>media/preview.jpg</preview_image>
    </media>
</theme>
```

created the `media/previw.jpg`, cleared the cache and everything works without touching composer.

Comment: Does not seem to work. And be aware that this problem is also happening for Themes, which are not "real modules".

Comment: I found `app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php` - but I have no clue from where this should be included.

Comment: Like I said, this worked on an older version. I will try it on a new version and get back with a result.

Comment: @Alex. See my update. It seams to work without touching composer even with the latest version.

Comment: Nope. I think you did not install the full magento via composer like me but used a git clone of the Magento2 main repo?

Comment: aaa...now I get it. I did use git clone.

Answer (score 3):

`registration.php` files of non-composer packages are handled by the file

```
app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php
```

This is included here: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/22629abe10f9c640fe47b6081d57fedccdea8e0f/composer.json

But it is not included in the product-base repo: https://github.com/magento/magento2-community-edition/blob/master/composer.json nor in https://packages.magento.com/_packages/magento_product-community-edition-2.0.0-rc.zip

So this looks like a bug to me which can be fixed by adding

```
"autoload": {
    "files": [
        "app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php"
    ]
},
```

to your `composer.json`

Answer (score 1):

For me, this worked:
delete all files in the `pub/static/frontend` and `var/view_preprocessed` directories, then reload the pages