# Problem Setting Production Mode - Deploying Static Content - Command returned non-zero exit code:

Tags: magento2, production-mode

I have a Magento 2 store which throws an error when entering production mode.

bin/magento deploy:mode:set production

Runs most the way until hitting deploy static content:

Something went wrong while deploying static content. See the error log for details.

```
Command returned non-zero exit code:
`/usr/bin/php7.0 -f /var/www/mage2/public_html/bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f en_GB en_US`
```

I can however run deploy static content without an error it seems.

In my logs i am getting a few errors for the theme with theme_dir not passed.

```
[InvalidArgumentException]
Required parameter 'theme_dir' was not passed
```

I am unsure why these are set to en_US however as would like them en_GB. I have all the themes set in the correct folders however i believe and am unsure how to resolve this error.

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/100011/36463

Comment: Glad I found this. I been facing problems turning Magento 2.3.2 to production mode and this helped solve the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Change the mode and skip the compilation:

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production --skip-compilation
```

And once the mode is switched you can deploy static content with GB locale.

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_GB
```

Magento default locale is `en_US` so you have to define your language.

If that fails, make sure your `/var` and `pub/` have the correct permissions

It could be that your PHP is exhausted so increasing the limit in `php.ini`  should help but skipping the compilation and compiling after switch is a good workaround.

Also, make sure your store in use has a valid theme selected, it might be that you are using a theme that doesn't exist in the system.

Comment: I have fixed this now a while ago cant remember what it was but just needed to tidy up the question. Will mark as a solution however thanks for your help!

Comment: Didn't realise how old this post was. It was bumped up by community :D Hope it will help someone else

Comment: This was back when i first tried Magento 2 i think