# Magento 2.3.1 CE visual swatch images showing blank

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, swatches, visualswatch

We have upgraded Magento 2.2.3 CE to Magento 2.3.1 CE recently we have been facing an issue i.e the visual swatch images are not displaying for the configurable product options on the frontend details page. `Visual swatch images are showing blank`. We did reindex and clear flush cache with no luck. Verified the same scenario on default magento2.3.1 CE on the local instance it's working as expected.

Please note for a simple product level we selected swatch image option settings as well.

We have an attribute called `floats_floatline_size` with below settings are at the attribute level

**Update Product Preview Image:** Yes

**Use Product Image for Swatch if Possible:** Yes

Please find the attached screenshots and review them and suggest.

Admin end attribute:

[image: Admin end attribute]

Configurable product options at admin end:

[image: Configurable produt options at admin end]

Frontend configurable product:

[image: Frontend configurable product]

2. Executed command : php bin/magento catalog:images:resize
   the catalog/product cache images are generated but not calling in the frontend.
3. varnish & cloud front cache from magemojo server UI interface but No luck
4. Not facing this issue on local same instance with same code and modules.

Please review and advise?

Comment: You may need to reindex and recache your website for these to work, if you are using varnish you may need to rm -rf var/cache/

Comment: yes @DavaGordon I followed the above steps but no luck is there any default magento 2 issue after upgrade. can u please advise

Comment: You could possibly try and regenerate the images using the following command "bin/magento catalog:image:resize" without the quotes

Comment: @DavaGordon i have executed above command followed same & removed i copied luma theme view.xml and paste it to  my custom theme & flushed cache and cleaned varnish & backend cleared image cache but no luck   https://gofile.io/?c=37r7Ty

Comment: If you inspect the swatches and copy the source of one is it valid as may be as simple as a permission issue

Comment: hu @DavaGordon inspect the element and took screenshot https://prnt.sc/owd6t4 please advise local reference: https://prnt.sc/owd813 please advise is there any code changes may i have to do?

Comment: If you look in your these do you have a Magneto_Swatch Folder

Comment: @NagarajuK Did you solve the problem? I have the same problem

Comment: Hi, @Kiwop I have debugged the issue with the 3rd party module called firebar configurable product due to this that issue occurred in our site. we have resolved the issue by upgrade the latest version then that issue was fixed.