# Does magento 2.3.3 accept external image server?

Tags: media-images, magento2.3.3, external-images

After successfully completed data migration, extra slash added on image url if image get from other server.

[image]

Note :

If url like this -> magento1.com/media/catalog/product/2/9/29594114-1.jpg instead of magento1.com/media/catalog/product\cache\f2b44f5a43f5823dafd935ad802e62ad/2/9/29594114-1.jpg image visible.

Answer (score 1):

[image: different server pub media urls]

Kindly please refer above screenshot and change this in secure/insecure section by
Loggin into Admin => Store => Configuration =>General => Web =>Base URLs(SECURE)/Base URLs both.

Comment: I just want clarity, m1 live m2 windows wamp localhost, is it images sync will work?  @Dinesh Rajput

Comment: you mean to say your magento 2 is local server and m1 site is live site. The images you want from live site m1 to local site m2 correct ?

Comment: Exactly,, We need to test before going to live.

Comment: No.... This will not work if thats the case because M1 site has skin/frontend path from your m1 site.

Comment: To make it work, You'll have to set path in admin "m1 site domain.com/media/

Comment: any help https://snipboard.io/dpZgXN.jpg  after set m1 image to m2.3.3 image url https://magento1.com/media/catalog/product\cache\f2b44f5a43f5823dafd935ad802e62ad\/9/2/922198-1.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You can configure your Magento 1.9 website Media URLs in your Magento 2.3.3 `Admin >> Store >> Configuration >> General >> Web >> Base URLs >> Base URL for User Media Files`

And `Admin >> Store >> Configuration >> General >> Web >> Base URLs (Secure) >> Base URL for User Media Files`

Please check the below screenshot for more information.

[image]

Comment: any help https://snipboard.io/dpZgXN.jpg after set m1 image to m2.3.3 image url https://magento1.com/media/catalog/product\cache\f2b44f5a43f5823dafd935ad802e62ad\/9/2/922198-1.jpg

Comment: Are you using any forward slash URLs in anywhere with your Magento 2.3.3? Can you please share the screenshot of your Magento 2.3.3 `core_config_data` table?

Comment: @zus - Please runs this **SELECT * FROM core_config_data WHERE value LIKE '%localhost%';** query in your Magento 2.3.3 database and share the screenshot with me.

Comment: screenshot - https://snipboard.io/PF32EM.jpg  @Ashok Dubariya

Comment: @zus - Which URLs did you configure for the `Base URL for User Media Files`? Can you please share the screenshot?

Comment: Magento 1 live url like www.website.com/media/ screenshot : https://snipboard.io/dJVq7f.jpg

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101457/discussion-between-zus-and-ashok-dubariya).