# Magento2 Convert Images to Responsive for entire site

Tags: magento2

Magento2 How can I convert entire website images to Responsiveas Google Page speed is recommending Images to be of proper size in Mobile

Comment: would this be link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/175224/regenerate-catalog-cache-images-issues be what you are after?

Comment: @HerveTribouilloy thanks for sharing. But this is not what I need