# In Magento 2, how to resolve "Required parameter 'theme_dir' was not passed" during migration from one server to another, without deleting the theme?

Tags: magento2, theme, migration

I copied the database to my development machine, from the test server. I changed the env.php file and I can even go to admin, but on frontend, I am getting the message "Required parameter 'theme_dir' was not passed" in the report folder, in the beginning of the error report. How can I resolve this? I think it is due to the Ultimo Infortis theme, but I don't know why is it happening. How can I fix this?

Comment: Duplicate - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/100011/required-parameter-theme-dir-was-not-passed

Comment: I don't want to delete the theme, as is suggested in that post that you wrote. Also, I want to fix the problem on frontend.