# My installation of Magento 2.2.5 has no "theme" table present in the database

Tags: magento-2.2.5, custom-theme, theme-overriding

I have a few issues with making my own custom theme, and against the documentation, I deleted my custom theme directly from the files. There is a good explanation of how to fix this issue [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/100011/required-parameter-theme-dir-was-not-passed).

Many answers for the **`"theme_dir"`** issue states to delete some entries from the `theme` table in the Magento database, however in my **Magento 2.2.5** Installatron I installed it from C Panel's installation two days ago & it has no such table in it. Does anyone know the **new tablename** that might be its replacement?

Thanks a bunch.

Comment: after theme installation , did you also configured it for some store view from content->Design->Configuration ?

Comment: Yes, Initially was configured for Luma, but then made a child theme for Luma that didn't work, so I deleted it and changed it back to Luma. Hence why i'm where I am right now.