# How to set "theme_dir" error. Magento 2

Tags: magento2, theme, localhost

I just copied the data form the site on which I'll work but after replacing that data with my custom **luma** first it gives me the **Permission** error I give them permission but after that it gives me

> 1 exception(s):
>   Exception #0 (InvalidArgumentException): Required parameter
>   'theme_dir' was not passed
>
> Exception #0 (InvalidArgumentException): Required parameter
>   'theme_dir' was not passed #1
>   Magento\Framework\View\Design\Fallback\Rule\Theme->getPatternDirs(array('area'
>   => 'frontend', 'locale' => 'en_GB', 'file' => 'i18n/en_GB.csv', 'theme_dir' => NULL)) called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/View/Design/FileResolution/Fallback/Resolver/Simple.php:124]

[image]

n also when I go to **admin panal** its not going to admin panel i.e. I'm using **Localhost** as you can see from the image but when I tries `locahost/magento/admin` it goes to `https//locahost/magento/admin` without my permission.

So how to solve this error I'll be really thankful

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/100011/required-parameter-theme-dir-was-not-passed check here

Comment: no ma'am we both have different issues last night I tried these solution but no one worked for me