# Magento2 : Error: Required parameter 'theme_dir' was not passed

Tags: magento2, theme, frontend-error

I had a theme and I deleted it from its folder and when I want to go back to Magento default theme I got this error.
I tried a lot of solutions from other threads but nothing work...

[image: error]

my website front gives me this error:

[image: Homepage front]

Comment: Check this https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/128333/59677

Comment: I already follow all the steps of this thread, I don't have any theme table in my core_config_data

Comment: Not in core_config_data table, the theme is a different table, Check this http://prntscr.com/qyby7j  you have to remove your theme row from this Table

Comment: These tables do not exist in my database